# How do I continue animating after the app is alive?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using this code to create a rotating animation in my application:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationDidBecomeActive(notification:)),
    name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(ViewController.applicationDidEnterBackground(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidEnterBackground, object: nil)

    animationStatus(true)
}

func animationStatus(_ enable: Bool) {
        if enable {
            if vinylStatus == "true" {
                resumeLayer(layer: vinylView.layer)
            } else {
                rotateImageView()
                resumeLayer(layer: vinylView.layer)
            }
        } else {
            pauseLayer(layer: vinylView.layer)
        }
    }
    
    func rotateImageView() {
        vinylStatus = "true"
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.vinylView.transform = self.vinylView.transform.rotated(by: .pi / 2)
        }) { (finished) in
            if finished {
                self.rotateImageView()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func pauseLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
        layer.speed = 0.0
        layer.timeOffset = pausedTime
    }

    func resumeLayer(layer: CALayer) {
        let pausedTime: CFTimeInterval = layer.timeOffset
        layer.speed = 1.0
        layer.timeOffset = 0.0
        layer.beginTime = 0.0
        let timeSincePause: CFTimeInterval = layer.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausedTime
        layer.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
```

But I want to continue animating after the application has been hidden and reopened and I use this code but animations stops and it doesn't work. How to fix this issue?

```
@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
            print("applicationDidBecomeActive")
    }
    
@objc func applicationDidEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification) {
            //pauseLayer(layer: vinylView.layer)
        }
}
```

**Update**

I don't understand. For example in `applicationDidBecomeActive`  I have only this code: `print("applicationDidBecomeActive")`.  And  if I open control center or notification center and return to app in debug I get this `applicationDidBecomeActive` but my animation doesn't stop. But if I hide app and return or lock iPhone and return to app I get this in debug too `applicationDidBecomeActive` but in this case animation stopes. Why this happens?

Comment: When you hide your app, it is suspended; the code stops running and all animations are removed automatically.

Comment: @matt I understand, but in what method should I start the animation again after opening the app?

Comment: You cannot start it "again". You just start it from scratch as if it had never existed. Your "resume" strategy won't work, there is nothing to resume.

Comment: @matt Ok. What I should do after hide and open app again? This `rotateImageView()`?

Comment: @matt And I should do this `rotateImageView()` in `applicationDidBecomeActive()`?

Comment: Looks like it, but I don't really do "should": I suggest you try it and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;**

You do not need a complicated start-pause-resume-stop code to continue animation when app comes to foreground.

You do not need to `observe` the `applicationDidBecomeActive` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` events either.

Instead, observe `applicationWillEnterForeground` event, and call `rotateImageView` function from `viewDidLoad` (to initially start the animation), and in `applicationWillEnterForeground` callback to re-start it when returning from background mode.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( self, selector: #selector(AnimationContinuationViewController.applicationWillEnterForeground(notification:)), name:UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)

    self.rotateImageView()
}

@objc func applicationWillEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification)  {
    print("applicationWillEnterForeground")
    self.rotateImageView()
}
```

This will fix the animation and also continue the animation from where it was stopped (while going to background).

So now, you can also remove `vinylStatus`, `animationStatus`, `pauseLayer`, `resumeLayer`, and other state handling functions unless they serve a different purpose.

---

---

**More details:**

When you open control center (or notification center), the app is only becoming `inactive`, and becomes `active` when the overlay (control center or notification center) is dismissed.

When the phone is locked, or you go to home screen, the app actually goes to background.

iOS apps do not execute any UI code when in background, so you need to re-start the animation when you come back from background mode.

Refer the [app life cycle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle#overview) for more details on this.

[image]

Comment: It is works fine! But I can't remove `animationStatus, pauseLayer, resumeLayer, ` because in the app I need to play or pause animation.

Comment: The logic you have implemented for pause and resume, seems complicated. You can use `self.vinylView.layer.`[removeAllAnimations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410810-removeallanimations), and `rotateImageView` to start and stop the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the animating function again

```
@objc func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {
            animationStatus(true)
    }
    
@objc func applicationDidEnterBackground(notification: NSNotification) {
            animationStatus(false)
        }
}
```

Comment: Nothing changes. In this case work this line `if vinylStatus == "true" { resumeLayer(layer: vinylView.layer) } ` same result

Comment: "applicationDidBecomeActive" function works perfectly ?

Comment: Yes, checked this with a breakpoint

Comment: I have found this "When your application goes into the background, all animations are removed from all layers. You will have to re-establish these animations each time you come to the foreground"

Comment: like this `rotateImageView()` ? Call everyone?

Comment: Call everyone so that animations start from the initial stage.

Comment: I don't understand. For example in `applicationDidBecomeActive ` I have only this code: `print("applicationDidBecomeActive")`.  And  if I open control center or notification center and return to app in debug I get this `applicationDidBecomeActive` but my animation doesn't stop. But if I hide app and return or lock iPhone and return to app I get this in debug too `applicationDidBecomeActive` but in this case animation stopes. Why this happens?